# Reading a huge text

Tags: c++, linux

I am trying to read a file like I use option `more` in Linux. I am just trying to make almost the same realization of `more`. 
My problem is when I read file in order like:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
.....................
ccccccccccccccccccccc
```

For, example: I have 100 strings in `txt.file`, in order which I showed you. So every string does not exceed the horizontal size of the console and goes after `ENTER`.

The program works excellent. I mean, if my information of a `txt.file` does not show fully, I just press `SPACE` and see another screen of my information from a file.

But if I put a huge text with long strings, It just read a file fully and shows me the end of the file. 
What do I do wrong with this? Might I not considered the horizontal size of a console? But I think, Linux thinks for me in this case.. Can you help me with this?

My arguments are:`./more 0 1.txt`

`./more` - make file, `0`- I beging on this string, `1.txt` -file name.

My code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>


int getch();
void printRecord(int& numStr,struct winsize w, std::vector<std::string>& lines);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct winsize w;
    char ch;
    ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &w);
    std::ifstream readRecord;
    std::vector<std::string> lines;

        std::string str;
        readRecord.open(argv[2]);
        int numStr= atoi(argv[1]);

        while (!readRecord.eof())
        {
            getline(readRecord, str);
            str.size();
            lines.push_back(str);
        }
            printRecord(numStr,w, lines);

         ch=getch();

           while(ch!='q'){
            if (ch==32)
            {
              numStr--;
                printRecord(numStr,w,lines);  
            }

            if (numStr>=lines.size()){
                break;}
           ch=getch();
            }

    return 0;
}

void printRecord(int& numStr,struct winsize w,std::vector<std::string>& lines)
{

    for (int i = numStr; i  <  numStr + w.winsize::ws_row-1; i++)
    {

        if (i>=lines.size())
            break;
        else
            std::cout << lines[i] << std::endl;

    }

    numStr += w.winsize::ws_row;
}

int getch()
{
    int ch;

    struct termios oldt, newt;
    tcgetattr( STDIN_FILENO, &oldt );
    newt = oldt;
    newt.c_lflag &= ~( ICANON | ECHO );
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt );
    ch = getchar();
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt );

    return ch;
}
```

Comment: @tambre and whaaaaat? I got another problem!!

Comment: @tambre Did you read my question?

Comment: `[...] if I put a huge text with long strings... [...]` please pick either a huge text or long strings, not both.  One problem at a time.

Comment: @MikeNakis I have got one problem with the huge strings

Comment: @NikitaGusev I *tried*. It consists of orderless ramblings and many illogical sentences. There's also quite a few obvious gammar errors. You should put more effort into your questions. Also don't add the programming language in the title. It's done automatically if there's a programming language tag on your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Linux doesn't "thinks for me in this case." If your code prints out the contents of the file, as is, then the contents of the file get printed to standard output. If the terminal is not big enough to show the contents of the file, only whatever fits on the screen will remain at the end. As the contents of the file get printed, the initial parts of the file will briefly appear, before the display scrolls off.

The terminal is not going to automatically paginate your program's output for you. That's the real `more`'s job. If you want to replicate `more`'s functionality, you must do it yourself.

Your program can obtain the size of the terminal display by making the `TIOCGWINSZ` ioctl, [as explained in the `tty_ioctl(4)` manual page](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman4/tty_ioctl.4.html), that you should read. After obtaining the terminal's size, it is going to be up to your program to calculate how much of the file's contents will fit on the screen, and to paginate it properly.

Things get complicated rather quickly, if you have to deal with multibyte UTF-8-encoded content, not to mention double-wide characters if your output contains certain Asian character sets. Computing the actual size of printed text, in the age of internationalization and localization, is surprisingly difficult. But, for plain Latin text, this should be sufficient. You should also set up a signal handler for `SIGWINCH`, as explained in that manual page, to detect changes to the terminal size, so that you can repaginate the contents of the file accordingly.

You can also consider using a higher-level library, like [curses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/), which might be useful in this case.

Comment: I tried to change `TIOCGWINSZ` on `SIGWINCH` but it doesn't solve my problem , it still reads fully and wait `SPACE`. But before i could read the file in the rigth order, and it was working

Comment: He at no point told you to change `TIOCGWINSZ` to `SIGWINCH`. He recommended that you should handle the `SIGWINCH` signal too.

Comment: No, but I'm confident that Google can. Or some good book, as you seem pretty clueless about basic things.